# Adding text after a particular text or word in textbox vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a combo box and textbox.

The combo box will have options for user to chose.

Textbox1 has text:- `Troubleshooting Steps:` set in properties of the textbox.

If user selects: `Rebooted PC` from combo box list, then presses a button it will add the text after `Troubleshooting Steps:`.

Example: `Troubleshooting Steps: Rebooted PC`

what i want to be able to do is add multiple selects one after other.

Example:

```
Troubleshooting Steps: Rebooted PC- Problem returned after reboot- Replaced part
```

I did some googling and found this code which ive changed to do part of it.

But the problem i have it adds the last text selected `Troubleshooting Steps:` pushing the first text selected to the end.

Whats Happening Example:

```
Troubleshooting Steps: (3rd)Replaced part- (2nd)Problem returned after reboot- (1st)Rebooted PC
```

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim text As String = TextBox1.Text

    Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf("Troubleshooting Steps:")

    Dim countChars As Integer
    countChars = "Troubleshooting Steps:".Length

    If index >= 0 Then
        text = text.Insert(index + countChars, ComboBox1.Text)
        TextBox1.Text = text
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the updated one, have a good one!

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'you can set the TextBox text either here or in the properties panel
    TextBox1.Text = "Troubleshooting Steps: "
    TextBox2.Text = "Follow up: "
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
     'MsgBox("Your message if nothing is selected in ComboBox1 when the button is pressed")
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & " - " & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    If ComboBox2.SelectedIndex < 0 Then
    'MsgBox("Your message if nothing is selected in ComboBox2 when the button is pressed")
    Else
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text & " - " & ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Chris, thats very interesting... but i need to have add the text after "Troubleshooting Steps:" Any thoughts on how to do that?

Comment: sorry i dint missed a bit in explanation, i would like a second button for "follow up:" with second combo box / button 2.